# Meteor Blaze Template - Dynamic field name

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm passing the arguments field1 and field2 to a blaze template and I would like to use them to get an object property inside that template.

For example:

```
field1 = "name", field2 = "total"

<h5 class="card-item-name">{{this[field1]}}</h5>
<span class="card-item-total">{{this[field2]}}</span>
```

Instead of:

```
<h5 class="card-item-name">{{this.name}}</h5>
<span class="card-item-total">{{this.total}}</span>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make yourself a little helper, say:

```
thisKey(key) {
 return this[key];
}
```

Then in your template use:

```
<h5 class="card-item-name">{{thisKey field1}}</h5>
<span class="card-item-total">{{thisKey field2}}</span>
```